# Establishing business hierarchy in log files – replace CURSOR by something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server as a warehouse to analyze log files. Those log files carry a kind of bussiness hierarchy (worker in this example):

```
Log Entry Id, Log Message
1           , Start Worker
2           , Do Cool Stuff
3           , Start Worker
4           , Do further cool stuff
5           , Start Worker
6           , This is a lot of working
7           , End worker
8           , End worker
9           , End worker
```

I need to relate the log entries to the current worker. The rule is quite simple: once a "Start worker" message is found, assign all following log entries to this worker. In the example hierarchy this means:

```
Log Entry Id, Log Message              , Worker
1           , Start Worker             , 1 (we take the entry id as worker id)
2           , Do Cool Stuff            , 1
3           , Start Worker             , 3
4           , Do further cool stuff    , 3
5           , Start Worker             , 5
6           , This is a lot of working , 5
7           , End worker               , 5
8           , End worker               , 3
9           , End worker               , 1
```

Currently I'm using a stored procedure iterating all log entries with a cursor which basically uses a stack to establish the relationship between log entries and workers:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateRelations
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE entries_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Id, LogMessage
    FROM LogEntries
    ORDER BY Id;

    DECLARE @Id BIGINT;
    DECLARE @LogMessage VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @ParentWorker BIGINT;
    DECLARE @WorkerStack VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    OPEN entries_cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM entries_cur INTO @Id, @LogMessage;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.GetParentWorker @WorkerStack OUT, @Id, @LogMessage, @ParentWorker OUT;

        UPDATE LogEntries
        SET ParentWorker = @ParentWorker
        WHERE Id = @Id;

        FETCH NEXT FROM entries_cur INTO @Id, @LogMessage;
    END;

    CLOSE entries_cur;
    DEALLOCATE entries_cur;
END;
GO
```

`GetParentWorker` is a stored procedure which uses the given `VARCHAR` variable `WorkerStack` as a stack. This means

- "Start worker" message leads to adding (push) the `Id` to that `VARCHAR`
- "End worker" message leads to removing and returning (pop) the last `Id` from that `VARCHAR`
- all other messages lead to just returning (read) the last `Id` from that `VARCHAR` without modifying it

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to replace this cursor construct by a `UPDATE` statement. I'm not that deep in SQL and SQL Server, but might it be possible to realize this by dynamic variable assignment, `CASE` and the usage of the return value of `GetParentWorker`?

Comment: I just tested all three approaches to determine the worker of a log entry with a dataset of 74674 log entries: the cursor took 57 seconds, Niks approach took 20 minutes and 19 seconds and Ians solution took 10 minutes and 53 seconds. Niks and Ians SELECT statements run very, very fast (<3 seconds), but the outer UPDATE statement seems to take a lot of time. I think it executes the SELECT statement for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is similar to Ian's, but I'll post for a slightly different approach to the indent level. I think you definitely want to put that indent level into the table with some indexing or this is going to be slow on large tables.

I'm using a CTE to calculate the indent level (basically just adding and subtracting one whenever we hit start or end, using a window function on preceding rows with a special case on ending worker in the current row). Outside of this toy solution, you'd want to limit the preceding rows to rows without an assigned worker and also rows up to the last time the level was zero before that.

Then we can just find the prior 'Start Worker' with the same level. These could probably be marked in pre-processing and indexed for quicker lookups.

**UPDATE:**

Simplified update statement by introducing window function CTE to calculate the worker id. This should reduce individual row lookups and improve performance in the update. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d41a8/19)

```
WITH 
    WorkerNestingLevel AS (
        SELECT
            AuditLog.LogId
        ,   AuditLog.LogMessage
        ,   SUM( CASE LogMessage WHEN 'Start Worker' THEN 1 WHEN 'End Worker' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY LogId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        +   CASE LogMessage WHEN 'End Worker' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [WorkerLevel]
        FROM
            AuditLog
    )
,   WorkerBatch AS (
        SELECT
            WorkerNestingLevel.LogId
        ,   MAX( CASE WorkerNestingLevel.LogMessage WHEN 'Start Worker' THEN WorkerNestingLevel.LogId ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY WorkerNestingLevel.WorkerLevel ORDER BY WorkerNestingLevel.LogId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS WorkerId
        FROM
            WorkerNestingLevel
    )
UPDATE
    AuditLog
SET
    WorkerId = WorkerBatch.WorkerId
FROM
    AuditLog
JOIN
    WorkerBatch ON (WorkerBatch.LogID = AuditLog.LogId);
```

Comment: Thanks Nik. Sounds very interesting. But, it's pretty late here (11pm, I need to catch some sleep), I'm looking for testing this tomorrow or on Monday. But yes, you are right, it's definitely possible that there might be entries between two `End Worker` entries which need to be assigned to the "outer" worker. PS: ATM, I don't get the idea of adding `1`if the current row is a `End worker` entry, but as I said, I need to charge my batteries :)

Comment: The end worker entry is just a hack because it's subtracting one from the level when it hits "End worker", but that row itself should really be part of the current level

Comment: I recommend this solution as its inner SELECT only takes 9 seconds for a table containing 853116 rows. Ians inner SELECT took almost two hours before I cancelled it and delivered ~550k rows.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for misunderstanding at the first attempt, hopefully I've understood this time that each 'End Worker' value cancels out one of the 'Start Worker's that precedes it.  Here it is using a WITH statement that generates a dataset with a field called indent which you need to establish how far back to look for the correct `[Log Entry ID]`.  Does that meet the requirement?

```
WITH indenttable AS (SELECT [Log Entry ID]
    , [Log Message]
    , ((SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM yourtable y2 
        WHERE [Log Message]='Start Worker' 
            AND y2.[Log Entry ID]<=yourtable.[Log Entry ID])
        -(SELECT COUNT(*)   
        FROM yourtable y2 
        WHERE [Log Message]='End Worker' 
            AND y2.[Log Entry ID]<yourtable.[Log Entry ID])) indent
    FROM yourtable)
UPDATE yourtable
SET worker=(
    SELECT TOP(1) [Log Entry ID]
    FROM indenttable y2 
    WHERE [Log Message]='Start Worker' 
        AND y2.[Log Entry ID]<=indenttable.[Log Entry ID]
        AND y2.indent<=indenttable.indent
    ORDER BY [Log Entry ID] DESC)
FROM indenttable JOIN yourtable ON indenttable.[Log Entry ID]=yourtable.[Log Entry ID];
```

Comment: This will work for the sample data, but if there are log entries after a nested worker ends, it will get the wrong id.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'm pretty surprised what's possible if one knows SQL Server :) I'll also have a look on your approach in the next days. And yes, it's definitely possible that there might be entries between two `End Worker` entries which need to be assigned to the "outer" worker.