# Most performant way of establishing a relationship in a log entry table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I already [asked a similar question and Ian Peters and Nik Shenoy provided awesome solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274701/establishing-business-hierarchy-in-log-files-replace-cursor-by-something-else/), but I forgot to mention that performance is a very interesting aspect. So I decided to ask a new question providing some more insights.

I'm maintaining an application which allows visual analyzation of a certain kind log files. The processing of log entries is mainly driven by stored procedures in a SQL Server database. One step of this processing is to relate the log entries to their corresponding workers and worker steps and to know when this worker instance was executed the last time.

Here is an example of the table containing the log entries:

```
Id , Time, LogCategory      , LogMessage
1  , 100 , WORKER_START     , Started worker
2  , 110 , WORKER_STEP_START, Entered Step 1
3  , 120 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do cool stuff
4  , 130 , WORKER_STEP_END  , Exited Step 1
5  , 140 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Some event here
6  , 150 , WORKER_START     , Started worker
7  , 160 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do more cool stuff
8  , 170 , WORKER_STEP_START, Entered Step 1
9  , 180 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do cool stuff
10 , 190 , WORKER_STEP_END  , Exited Step 1
11 , 200 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Bad event, exit worker
12 , 210 , WORKER_END       , Exited worker
13 , 220 , WORKER_STEP_START, Entered Step 2
14 , 230 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do further cool stuff
15 , 240 , WORKER_STEP_END  , Exited Step 2
16 , 250 , WORKER_END       , Exited worker
```

I want to

- add the entry id of the worker this entry corresponds to
- add the entry id of the worker step this entry corresponds to
- update the WORKER_START entry and set the maximum timestamp of entries belonging to this worker.

This would result in:

```
Id , Time, LogCategory      , LogMessage             , Worker, Step  , LastUpdate
1  , 100 , WORKER_START     , Started worker         , 1     , null  , 250
2  , 110 , WORKER_STEP_START, Entered Step 1         , 1     , 2     , null
3  , 120 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do cool stuff          , 1     , 2     , null
4  , 130 , WORKER_STEP_END  , Exited Step 1          , 1     , 2     , null
5  , 140 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Some event here        , 1     , null  , null
6  , 150 , WORKER_START     , Started worker         , 6     , null  , 210
7  , 160 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do more cool stuff     , 6     , null  , null
8  , 170 , WORKER_STEP_START, Entered Step 1         , 6     , 8     , null
9  , 180 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do cool stuff          , 6     , 8     , null
10 , 190 , WORKER_STEP_END  , Exited Step 1          , 6     , 8     , null
11 , 200 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Bad event, exit worker , 6     , null  , null
12 , 210 , WORKER_END       , Exited worker          , 6     , null  , null
13 , 220 , WORKER_STEP_START, Entered Step 2         , 1     , 13    , null
14 , 230 , SOMETHING_ELSE   , Do further cool stuff  , 1     , 13    , null
15 , 240 , WORKER_STEP_END  , Exited Step 2          , 1     , 13    , null
16 , 250 , WORKER_END       , Exited worker          , 1     , null  , null
```

Currently I'm doing this by executing this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateRelations
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE entries_cur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT Id, LogCategory
      FROM LogEntries
      ORDER BY Id;

    DECLARE @Id BIGINT;
    DECLARE @LogCategory VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @Worker BIGINT;
    DECLARE @WorkerStack VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @Step BIGINT;
    DECLARE @StepStack VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    OPEN entries_cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM entries_cur INTO @Id, @LogCategory;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.GetParentWorker @WorkerStack OUT, @Id, @LogCategory, @Worker OUT;
        EXEC dbo.GetParentStep @StepStack OUT, @Id, @LogCategory, @Step OUT;

        UPDATE LogEntries
        SET
          Worker = @Worker,
          Step = @Step
        WHERE Id = @Id;

        UPDATE LogEntries
           SET LastUpdate = @Time
           WHERE Id = @Worker;

        FETCH NEXT FROM entries_cur INTO @Id, @LogCategory;
    END;

    CLOSE entries_cur;
    DEALLOCATE entries_cur;
END;
```

`GetParentWorker` and `GetParentStep` are stored procedures using the given `VARCHAR` variables `WorkerStack` and `StepStack` as a stack. This means

- "WORKER_START"/"WORKER_STEP_START" entry leads to adding (push) the Id to that VARCHAR
- "WORKER_END"/"WORKER_STEP_END" entry leads to removing and returning (pop) the last Id from that VARCHAR
- all other entries lead to just returning (read) the last Id from that VARCHAR without modifying it.

This procedure runs on ~850k entries in 24 minutes and 33 seconds. I also tried a slight modification of that stored procedure. There I switched from a normal cursor to an update cursor and I introduced a temporary table to calculate the `LastUpdate` of a worker:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateRelations
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE entries_cur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT Id, LogCategory
      FROM LogEntries
      ORDER BY Id
      FOR UPDATE OF Worker, Step;

    DECLARE @Id BIGINT;
    DECLARE @LogCategory VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @Worker BIGINT;
    DECLARE @WorkerStack VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @Step BIGINT;
    DECLARE @StepStack VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    TRUNCATE TABLE LogEntries_LastUpdate;

    OPEN entries_cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM entries_cur INTO @Id, @LogCategory;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.GetParentWorker @WorkerStack OUT, @Id, @LogCategory, @Worker OUT;
        EXEC dbo.GetParentStep @StepStack OUT, @Id, @LogCategory, @Step OUT;

        UPDATE LogEntries
        SET
          Worker = @Worker,
          Step = @Step
        WHERE CURRENT OF entries_cur;

        INSERT INTO LogEntries_LastUpdate(Id, Time)
        VALUES (@Worker, @Time);

        FETCH NEXT FROM entries_cur INTO @Id, @LogCategory;
    END;

    CLOSE entries_cur;
    DEALLOCATE entries_cur;

    UPDATE le
    SET le.LastUpdate = CAST(0.5 * (CAST(le.LastUpdate AS numeric(12,1)) + CAST(lelu.Time AS numeric(12,1)) + ABS(le.LastUpdate - lelu.Time)) AS int)
    FROM LogEntries le
      JOIN (
        SELECT Id=ilelu.Id, Time=MAX(ilelu.Time)
        FROM LogEntries_LastUpdate ilelu
        GROUP BY ilelu.Id) lelu
      ON lelu.Id = le.Id;
END;
```

This modification takes longer than the first version I used which was quite surprising. So I thought a non-cursor solution had to be found and Ian Peters and Nik Shenoy  came up with something like this:

```
WITH LogWithWorkerLevel AS (
  SELECT LogEntries.*
    , SUM(CASE LogCategory WHEN 'WORKER_START' THEN 1 
                           WHEN 'WORKER_END' THEN -1
                           ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      + CASE LogCategory WHEN 'WORKER_END' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [WorkerLevel]
    , SUM(CASE LogCategory WHEN 'WORKER_STEP_START' THEN 1 
                           WHEN 'WORKER_STEP_END' THEN -1
                           ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      + CASE LogCategory WHEN 'WORKER_STEP_END' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [StepLevel]
  FROM LogEntries
)
UPDATE LogWithWorkerLevel
SET
  Worker = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id 
    FROM LogWithWorkerLevel AS Lookup 
    WHERE 
      Lookup.Id <= LogWithWorkerLevel.Id 
      AND Lookup.WorkerLevel = LogWithWorkerLevel.WorkerLevel
      AND Lookup.LogCategory = 'WORKER_START'
    ORDER BY Id DESC)
  , Step = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id 
    FROM LogWithWorkerLevel AS Lookup 
    WHERE 
      Lookup.Id <= LogWithWorkerLevel.Id 
      AND Lookup.StepLevel = LogWithWorkerLevel.StepLevel
      AND Lookup.LogCategory = 'WORKER_STEP_START'
    ORDER BY Id DESC);
```

Here we don't care about `LastUpdate` since it's just an idea by now. While the `SELECT` statement of the temporary table `LogWithWorkerLevel` runs blazing fast (9 seconds), the `UPDATE` statement takes pretty long, longer than the cursor I started with.

Sorry for this long explanation to come to this short question: Do you see a way to boost the performance of this processing using a stored procedure?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Here is the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE LogEntries (
    Id int,
    Time int,
    LogCategory varchar (128),
    LogType varchar (128),
    Worker int NULL,
    Step int NULL,
    LastUpdate int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_le_Id PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_le_LogDomain ON LogEntries(LogDomain);
CREATE INDEX IDX_le_Worker ON LogEntries(Worker);
CREATE INDEX IDX_le_Step ON LogEntries(Step);
```

According the execution plan: it takes quite long (4+ hours) to get the actually executed execution plan. So, I take a look into the estimated execution plan (if it's called so in English, my SSMS speaks German):

- In total 55% costs go on the cursor creation. Seems to be a "dynamic" cursor and the most expensive operations are a "Clustered Index Insert" (29%) and a "Clustered Index Search" (25%)

  - Another 23% go on the "Clustered Index Update" where I set the `Worker` and `Step` of a log entry.
  - In total 17% go on the UPDATE of the `LastUpdate`.

Here is the execution plan:

[image: Estimated execution plan]

**UPDATE 2**

After four days and eight hours, the query (including the creation of the exact execution plan) was successfully executed:

[image: Actual execution plan]

(If you're interested in the execution plan itself, just let me know.)

So, there are two main reasons for this long duration:

- The filter nodes in the two lower branches get a 12 digit count of rows.
- Some sort nodes seem to cause a data overflow in tempdb.

I'm not sure if it's possible to fix that.

I also modified the cursor to conditionally execute the `UPDATE` statements. So I inserted an `IF` statement. And that boosted the query from 24 minutes to 3 minutes.

Comment: When you check the execution plan are their any index suggestions?  Those queries look like they would perform well if the table is properly indexed.

Comment: Without full table DDL and sample data, we can only guess.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I updated the question and added the DDL statement as well as an execution plan. And I wanted to add that I omitted some columns which aren't used in the stored procedure in order to have the question as small as possible.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg: I updated the question and added the DDL statement as well as an execution plan. And I wanted to add that I omitted some columns which aren't used in the stored procedure in order to have the question as small as possible.

Comment: Is that the execution plan of your original SP or the one Ian Peters and Nick Shenoy gave you?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg: It's the execution plan of the original stored procedure. I'll start the `UPDATE`statement of Ian and Nick and post the execution plan.